# Algorithm for estimating quantities with different numerical constraints

Tags: algorithm

I would like to write an algorithm that will help calculate the composition of a menu that will suit nutritionally all the required nutritional values such as the amount of protein, the amount of calcium, etc. without exceeding the maximum in any of the values.

Is there a particular algorithm template that can fit this problem?
I would appreciate any intention

Comment: I think you will need to be more specific in your question as it is too broad to be answered without writing a book :P. Maybe an example of your starting data, your expected goals, etc.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming